# All Changes are Synced with Layers

Tags: layers

I wanted to copy my mesh to another layer before I apply a mirror modifier. I copied it, went into an empty layer, and pasted it. However, every change I make seems to be synced on the two layers somehow, so if I apply the mod, it applies on the other layer too. Does anyone know how to help me? This has been not letting me make much progress.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to duplicate the mesh (Shift+D), so that both meshes are not linked, then you can move it to whatever layer you want.

Comment: Copy pasting should be used exclusively to transfer between to distinct running instances of Blender or two separate windows, not to duplicate objects in the same file

Comment: I tried Shift + D, and I duplicated it to another layer. However, they are somehow still linked. I did u -> unlink and it didn't change. Whenever I apply the mirror modifier, it applies to both meshes.